# best approach to implement this email service

Tags: spring, email

I am working on a website in Spring, My website gathers info of jobs positions as well the email to which to send applicant resume to (e.g jobs@microsoft.com)

I want users to be able to send emails thru my website to different jobs positions emails, Sending emails thru the website system will send a designed html email to the job email.

So how would I implement it? Should I find unlimited email hosting and create an account for each user? (does that even exist with combination of spring?)
or is there some other way without asking the user for his email and password (nobody in their right mind will trust that.).

what about spam filters? If I create a new domain and open new email accounts will I be considered as spam?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost certainly you'll want a single email account to send the messages, but can use the "reply-to" parameter to have replies go to the user sending the application resume if desired.  GMail (or other public mailing service) can be configured for this purpose, see the [mailSender](https://github.com/gmazza/tightblog/blob/master/app/src/main/resources/spring-beans.xml#L145) object and [MailManagerImpl](https://github.com/gmazza/tightblog/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/apache/roller/weblogger/business/MailManagerImpl.java) class in my open source project for a working example of using Gmail with Spring’s email support.